# Could my glass buildings last for thousands of years?

Tags: construction, data-storage

In my story world, I was thinking about having glass structures built by a prior civilization to preserve information.  The reason the structures would be made of glass would be because the glass the structures are built of are also used as a giant data storage device.  Kind of like the glass etching technique they’re trying for storing greater volumes of digital data.  The scientists developing this glass-based digital storage are currently saying that one of the pluses of this technology is that it could safely store digital data for thousands of years.  Since the civilization that built these structures existed thousands of years before the current events in my story world, I figured glass data storage would be an ideal option for preserving data from this civilization.  So what I need to know is whether or not a glass building would be inherently structurally weak and collapse fairly quickly, or if it could be done in a way that would be structurally solid, and could realistically last for thousands of years.  So, in other words, could my glass buildings last for thousands of years?

Details:

- I’m thinking that they’ve been up for about 3-5,000 years, I know this is kind of a wide spectrum, but you should probably assume the 5,000 years for a worst case scenario.
- It doesn’t have to be a specific type of glass.  Any kind of glass is on the table, so whatever lasts the longest.  Spare no expense.
- The buildings are likely pyramid-like.  Like ziggurats, or something similar in design.
- Also, this is assuming nobody’s tried to purposefully destroy them, like bomb them, etc.  Also assuming nobody’s like accidentally crashed into them, stolen material from them, etc.  This is assuming no harm to the buildings from humans (I’m not sure if any humans are even living near these structures).  Just natural forces working on the structures.
- The buildings have to still be functional (at least for the most part).  Parts of the structures could be missing or damaged, but it should be mostly intact and functional, think like the condition pyramids or ziggurats are in at worst.

Comment: Depends on how much glass you use which makes things easy if you spare no expense. For example, sapphire glass and lots of it.

Comment: What kind of buildings do you want? And why are the buildings *made of* data storage instead of the data storage being *inside* the buildings, as is conventional?

Comment: @Cadence Thank you for that, sorry I forgot to clarify that point.  I added those details to my question.  The building type is a sort of pyramid-like structure.

Comment: glass is actually a liquid from a physical-material standpoint. so while it's *extremely* slow, it "flows" downwards each year. you might have seen very old glass windows which appear thicker at the lower part ofthe pane. this takes several decades, but after 200 years or so it will be an issue.

Comment: @clockw0rk that's a common misconception https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions

Comment: @clockw0rk That old glass sags is an often repeated statement, but I really doubt it is true. I personally have 2 400 years old leaded glass windows in my house. My father rescued these in 1980 from a a to be demolished mansion build in 1617. All the panes (about 6x8") are of uniform thickness. And I have seen much older glass in churches and the like that also didn't show this. It is known that old glass was in many cases non-uniform in thickness right when it was made and often installed with the thick end down. This may be the source of the myth.

Comment: @MJD Grin.. Your Wikipedia link just confirmed what I just typed.

Comment: define last, is ir maintain a rough heap in the general shape of, like the pyramids, or does it still need to be functional.

Comment: @John it has to be functional.

Comment: One big problem you will have is keeping people from steeling materials, that is what did the worse damage to the pyramids after all. Look free cut glass!

Comment: @John see the section in my question that says “just natural forces working on the structures”.

Comment: @KalMadda I was not a hundred percent sure, they were not trying to destroy the pyramids it was just humans being lazy.

Comment: I believe there are ancient, mysterious glass buildings in The_Gentleman_Bastards series. If Scott Lynch can do it, so can you.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Lycurgus Cup]

### Yes. The structure isn't too hard, but the data is a bit tricker

We have ancient glassware from Roman and even earlier times. It's in good condition. That cup pictured is the Lycurgus Cup; you can still even admire the artwork on it.

Contrary to popular opinion, glass won't flow over time; the 'flow' that you can see in cathedral windows is an artifact of the pouring during the manufacturing process.

So yes, glass will last, and it will probably not even need to be fancy glass.

You may need some base isolators or at least a good mechanical design that allows some movement; glass will HATE earthquakes. Still, the pyramids of Egypt still stand and we can make glass that is mechanically superior to limestone in almost every way.

However: data written on a sufficiently small scale may well prove fragile. Tiny oxidations of trace elements, tiny mechanical distortions or elastic deformations can ruin it. It's only on the nanometre scale, after all.

Possibly free standing glass blocks with data sitting inside cavities inside structural blocks will mitigate this. Or you could try using exotic glass, like nearly pure silica or nearly pure alumina or whatever they are currently experimenting on.
(EDIT: As per a comment by @biziclop, writing onto crystalline quartz even at the nanometre scaled is projected to have good data integrity more or less forever.)

One interesting, 'Rule of cool' possibility is using gold nanoparticles dispersed in the glass; this is how the Lycurgus Cup gets its colour. Gold in glass should be stable more or less forever; you just need to imagine how to encode data and get the nanoparticles into the glass in orderly fashion (near future tech).

This is my recommendation.

[image: Limestone < glass]

Comment: Yes good point about the gold in glass. Could even have gold and platinum nano particles for increased data density.

Comment: As for encoding, you might want to look into something like this: https://www.zmescience.com/research/technology/quartz-disk-5d-storage-52543/

Comment: For us old dogs learning a new trick today, here's a link explaining that [glass, in fact, does not "flow"](https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/how-does-glass-change-over-time/#:~:text=Contrary%20to%20the%20urban%20legend,was%20created%2C”%20Cima%20says.).

Comment: I'm not convinced that the survival of small handheld glass items which experience virtually no external forces whatsoever is a good indicator that a glass building can survive the mechanical stresses experienced by a massive structure. There have been discoveries of wooden tools that are tens of thousands of years old; that doesn't imply you can build a wood structure that will last thousands of years. I generally agree with this answer, but don't think the survival of glass trinkets says much about the longevity of glass buildings.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That's why I also reference the pyramids, which are made of limestone, and point out that a good, earthquake proof design will be necessary. The best glasses / composites are superior to limestone in every way.

Answer (score 14):

Glass is structurally sound; but I would worry about surface damage. One thing you might do is enclose your "data glass" in a shell of more glass. Perhaps a foot or even two feet all around, to take scratches, impacts and cracks. Maybe that's why they are arranged in structures like buildings; the glass shell provides both protection and physical space around the core glass for data access machinery to operate. (The core glass doesn't have to be rectangular, it could be pyramidal or even spherical.)

The outer glass can be designed tougher to protect the data glass. And the outer glass can be polished to make the data glass readable.

This might add to the mystery in your story.

Beat 1: Most of these big blocks have rough surfaces and are opaque white, but in some there are polished points, and we can see they have a "core" of a different kind of glass.

Beat 2: When we polish spots on a few blocks with opaque outer glass, we realize that all blocks have this "core" glass.

Beat 3: In trying to (non-destructively) determine the makeup of this core glass, our hero shines X-rays and lasers of various frequencies through the core glass, and discover some of these frequencies, at the correct angles, produce unexpected patterns, highly ordered. A surprise.

Beat 4: Our hero realizes this is data of some sort, and try to discover all the frequencies that cause this response, and unravels a protocol that produces a consistent and finite set of symbols for exactly half of the frequencies that produce an ordered response. But like hieroglyphs, our hero cannot decode them as words.

Beat 5: The other half of the frequencies that cause a response, our hero could not figure out at first, get figured out: They are images. Pictures in the glass.

Beat 6: Our hero understands *addressing*, how the combinations of frequencies used to elicit words, translated to the higher frequencies that elicit images, match up: This means the Text is attached to the Images. This lets our hero puzzle out the words, and the language, and start to decode the data.

And so on. The next surprise is in what it reveals, and what needs to be done about it.

Comment: not just scratches, thermal shock, day night cycle can break almost any rock down. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermo-mechanical_fatigue.

Comment: @John True. That can be ameliorated by glass composition. Another approach would be to make the outer "protective" glass tougher, or perhaps reflective to infrrared radiation. Or perhaps there is a way to engineer the glass to fail from the outside in; which would explain why the glass "bricks" appear frosted; this is the very slow decay of the original polished surface of the glass. And the site of this discovery may be underground, or in a deep cave system with a relatively constant temperature, to minimize thermal cycling.

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers talk about how glass will work and won't degrade over time, it might not be your best bet for long term, high-tech storage.  Bullet proof glass is actually made of synthetic sapphires. These look almost identical to glass, but are much more durable.  We can currently produce them on demand in larger sizes than you might be thinking of. Building-sized creations would be quite possible for a society even slightly ahead of modern day.

Impurities introduced into the creation process can colour the sapphires to almost any colour allowing for data storage in a visually appealing way.  You can also have the angle of facets on individual crystals bending a laser's light as a method of data storage.

Comment: Note: Sapphire's made in small pieces (max 300mm diameter boule) and would be great, but isn't currently used for transparent armor. Most armor glass is still regular silica glass, with ALON and Spinel as expensive lightweight options. Or just plain polycarbonate.

Comment: Agree that colouration is a potential way to store data. But you won't have facets if it's glass, by definition. Glasses are amorphous on the atomic level, even Al2O3, although there are many materials that look pretty glassy and do have very fine crystals, like glass-ceramics. Upvoted.

Comment: Luxium Solutions website talks about growing windows of sapphire 1 ft x 3ft using edge fed growth. But as I said in the original answer the creators would have to be slightly, (but not far) ahead of modern technology to produce buildings of the stuff.

Comment: As for facets for storage I was thinking with sapphires, not glass.

Answer (score 0):

**Humans are Highly Destructive of Pretty Useless Things**

You might have some buildings solidly, thickly surrounded on all sides including bottom by seamless glass that resists sandblast, warm enough to never freeze and experience frost-heave and frost-crack, carefully shaped so that lensing never melts internal structural members, etc.

However, the Pyramids have taught us, when humans are nearby who aren't invested in the sanctity of the object, they will steal it for their own uses.  The Great Wall gets pieces of it stolen all the time.  Just building materials from the nice outer shell of the Pyramids, and bragging trophies for many old buildings.  This is true for primitive humans, stone age, modern, what have you.  If something looks valuable, someone will try and break in to take it.

Roots of plants eventually work their way into all surfaces, and then into all solid materials.  A low-water location with little greenery is the only place your glass buildings will remain unbreached after thousands of years.  Possible  counter : toxic building materials.

Comment: Sorry if I didn’t make it clear enough, but in the details section of my question I said “Just natural forces working on the structures”.  I’m assuming no human destruction.  I added a little more in that portion to make it clearer that no intentional or accidental human damage includes stealing from the structures.

Comment: That said, I’m not entirely disregarding the possibility of some material theft.  I’m sure maybe a few travelers may have come across these structures and decided to take souvenirs, but this should be very limited.  I’m thinking the structures are in an isolated place away from human civilization.  PS I meant “including” in the last sentence of my other comment.  Thank you for the answer about roots, that’s something I hadn’t really thought about much.  Are roots a big problem for the ziggurats in South America?  Or is there some way they like work around the structures?

Comment: @KalMadda:  As an example, the big pyramid at Chichen Itza was [almost completely covered in vegetation by the mid-19th century.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Charnay_chichenitza.png)  It's not clear to me how long it had been abandoned by that point, but you're probably looking at something in the range of 300–600 years — significantly less time than you want your structures to survive.

Answer (score -1):

No.
Glass is a liquid material like honey. Glass has no crystalline structure like stones have. Elder glass from past centuries, built in windows, flow down to the under edge of the plane window glass panels. The glass thickness is so double or more thicker, than on the upper edge of the plane glass. The flowing gets slowly but it flows. So your some thousands of year old building will shrink and get lower every century. Glass seam stable, but it is not. I was glass worker in past.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but according to several other people here, the “flowing glass” is a commonly believed myth.

Comment: It is indeed a myth.  The reason that old glass is thicker at the bottom is that old glassmakers were less capable than modern ones and putting a pane in thick-side-up doesn't make sense if you already have an uneven pane.

Comment: Its not a myth. At the University my brother did study about materials and is now working worldwide in laboratories since over 30 years. His best study friend is worldwide well known as sience expert for glass and its characteristics. For example his last diploma and research at the University was about, how fast grows a cut in glass, when you break it.

Comment: I remember, it was over the speed of sound. So I will ask him next, about the floating of glass. Glass is no crystalline material, like gemstones, diamonds, or metals or graphit. It is like water, or honey. You cannot store information in glass over centuries, like you can is crystalline grown silicate waffers for IT. Glass is honey